# Rendering a table in Angular 1 without ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html-table

I'm trying to find a better way for rendering a large table in Angular than using ngRepeat.

I tried using [one-time](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression#one-time-binding) `{{::binding}}`s, but found the initial render time remained unchanged, which wasn't satisfactory.

Back to the drawing board, I'm trying to find a much more performant method for assembling data into a HTML table in the DOM. I've been trying to use angular.element() to assemble all the parts into a whole, but with no luck. Any insights?

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.directive('myTable', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      ngModel: "=",
    },
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      scope.$watch('ngModel', function() {

        if (typeof scope.ngModel == 'undefined') {
        console.log("ngModel not defined yet");
          return;
        }
        element.html('');

        var table = angular.element('<table/>');
        var tbody = angular.element('<tbody/>');

        scope.ngModel.forEach(function(m) {
          var tr = angular.element('<tr/>');

          m.fields.forEach(function(f) {
            var td = angular.element('<td/>')
            td.text(f.value);
            td.append(tr);
          });

          tr.append(tbody);
        })

        tbody.append(table);
        table.append(element);

      })
    }
  }
});

app.controller('AppController', function($scope) {
  $scope.data = [{
      fields: [{
        value: 1,
        metadata: ""
      }, {
        value: 2,
        metadata: ""
      }, {
        value: 3,
        metadata: ""
      }, {
        value: 4,
        metadata: ""
      }, {
        value: 5,
        metadata: ""
      }, ]
    },
    {
      fields: [{
        value: 6,
        metadata: ""
      }, {
        value: 7,
        metadata: ""
      }, {
        value: 8,
        metadata: ""
      }, {
        value: 9,
        metadata: ""
      }, {
        value: 10,
        metadata: ""
      }, ]
    }
  ]
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <div ng-app="app" ng-controller="AppController">
    <my-table ng-model="data"></my-table>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: what is my-table?

Comment: <my-table> is the Angular directive I am trying to use to render the table- see the code

Comment: yes thats what, where is the code for my-table?

Comment: See the Angular directive in the code snippet - `app.directive('myTable', function() {...`

Comment: Don't you have `appends` backwards?  Should it no be `element.append(table)`? Similarly for `td`, `tr` and `tbody`.

Comment: Wow, egg on my face! It works. Is this generally the fastest way to assemble HTML in Angular without using ng-repeat?

Comment: @schnauss You know you can use [**one time binding**](https://toddmotto.com/angular-one-time-binding-syntax/) with `ng-repeat`, right? `<ANY ng-repeat="item in ::list"></ANY>`

Comment: @schnauss Also, as a general rule of thumb, any time you find yourself doing manual DOM manipulation in angularjs, you are likely doing something wrong. (not always, but usually the case)

Comment: I suspect that you're saving a number of digest cycles on all of the table elements, but other than the initial rendering of the table, there will be no other performance improvements. On a large dataset and on a more complex table, this will still get to be extremely sluggish. You will be better served in the long run with a virtual scroll approach or one of the other mature angular data table implementations that have already dealt with this.

Comment: You should try the [DataTables](https://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/#/welcome) plugin! I personally use it all the time to display data in tables.

Comment: @MikeFeltman Rendering a table with nested `ng-repeat` statements creates a child scope for each element in the table as well as a watcher for each data element. That could be hundreds or thousands of watchers and scopes. It is much more efficient to render a table with a single watcher and a single scope..

Comment: @georgeawg, true, but once the OP starts doing anything with the table beyond just inserting plain rows, columns and text I think all of that will go quickly by the wayside.

Comment: @AlexLeibovich have you tried: https://www.ag-grid.com/ It looks awesome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is inappropriate to involve the [ngModel controller](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController) in a directive that has no user input elements. Also isolate scope is unnecessary. Evaluate the `table-data` attribute in the watch expression.

Also of course, fix the backwards append statements:

```
app.directive('myTable', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    ̶s̶c̶o̶p̶e̶:̶ ̶{̶
      ̶n̶g̶M̶o̶d̶e̶l̶:̶ ̶"̶=̶"̶,̶
    ̶}̶,̶
    ̶r̶e̶q̶u̶i̶r̶e̶:̶ ̶'̶n̶g̶M̶o̶d̶e̶l̶'̶,̶
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      scope.$watch(attrs.tableData ̶'̶n̶g̶M̶o̶d̶e̶l̶'̶, function(data) {
        if (data) {
          console.log("table-data not defined yet");
          return;
        }
        element.html('');

        var table = angular.element('<table/>');
        var tbody = angular.element('<tbody/>');

        data.forEach(function(m) {
          var tr = angular.element('<tr/>');

          m.fields.forEach(function(f) {
            var td = angular.element('<td/>')
            td.text(f.value);
            ̶t̶d̶.̶a̶p̶p̶e̶n̶d̶(̶t̶r̶)̶;̶ tr.append(td);
          });

          ̶t̶r̶.̶a̶p̶p̶e̶n̶d̶(̶t̶b̶o̶d̶y̶)̶;̶ tbody.append(tr);
        })

        ̶t̶b̶o̶d̶y̶.̶a̶p̶p̶e̶n̶d̶(̶t̶a̶b̶l̶e̶)̶;̶ table.append(tbody);
        ̶t̶a̶b̶l̶e̶.̶a̶p̶p̶e̶n̶d̶(̶e̶l̶e̶m̶e̶n̶t̶)̶;̶ element.append(table);    
      })
    }
  }
});
```

Usage:

```
 <my-table table-data="data"></my-table>
```

## [THE DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/15ploVpfTzbpURIcxkOl?p=preview)

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.directive('myTable', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      scope.$watch(attrs.tableData, function(data) {
        console.log(data);
        if (!data) {
          console.log("tableData not defined yet");
          return;
        }
        element.html('');

        var table = angular.element('<table/>');
        var tbody = angular.element('<tbody/>');

        data.forEach(function(m) {
          var tr = angular.element('<tr/>');

          m.fields.forEach(function(f) {
            var td = angular.element('<td/>')
            td.text(f.value);
            tr.append(td);
          });
          
          
          tbody.append(tr);
        })

        table.append(tbody);
        element.append(table);

      })
    }
  }
});

app.controller('ctrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.data = [{
      fields: [{
        value: 1,
        metadata: ""
      }, {
        value: 2,
        metadata: ""
      }, {
        value: 3,
        metadata: ""
      }, {
        value: 4,
        metadata: ""
      }, {
        value: 5,
        metadata: ""
      }, ]
    },
    {
      fields: [{
        value: 6,
        metadata: ""
      }, {
        value: 7,
        metadata: ""
      }, {
        value: 8,
        metadata: ""
      }, {
        value: 9,
        metadata: ""
      }, {
        value: 10,
        metadata: ""
      }, ]
    }
  ]
})
```

```html
<script src="//unpkg.com/angular/angular.js"></script>
  <body ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
    <my-table table-data="data"></my-table>
  </body>
```